# Cosmodb reply message length error performing a find using the mongo java driver

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

Using the Mongo Java Driver version 3.4.2
Trying to perform a find query on a collection that contains around 700 documents has started throwing the following exception.
This did not happen when the collection was smaller.
The limits look to be set during the connection process.

```
! com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The reply message length 4812632 is less than the maximum message length 4194304
! at com.mongodb.connection.ReplyHeader.<init>(ReplyHeader.java:74)
! at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:498)
! at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224)
! at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.receiveMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:96)
! at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.receiveMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:440)
! at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:112)
! at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168)
! at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289)
! at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:176)
! at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:216)
! at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:207)
! at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:113)
! at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:516)
! at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:510)
! at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:431)
! at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:404)
! at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:510)
! at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)
! at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
! at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
! at com.mongodb.OperationIterable.iterator(OperationIterable.java:47)
! at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.iterator(FindIterableImpl.java:151)
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error information, I reviewed the related source codes of [MongoDB Java driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) which include [`ReplyHeader.java`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/r3.4.2/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/connection/ReplyHeader.java), and then I think it's a possible compatiblity bug for CosmosDB using MongoDB wire protocol, but I'm not sure for that without reproducing your issue. Please post a feedback to [feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com) to report this issue to help resolving it.