# The reply message length 4217268 is less than the maximum message length 4194304

Tags: java, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I'm facing an issue when trying to get documents from a Cosmos DB database: "The reply message length 4217268 is less than the maximum message length 4194304"

It's a huge amount of documents, however, I don't think there is any doc with more than 16 mb.

I'm using Java Mongo API.

There is any workaround for this issue?

Adding some code:

```
    private StageRepository stageRepository;

    @Autowired
    public StageDatabaseDataProvider(final StageRepository stageRepository) {
        this.stageRepository = stageRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Result> loadBulk(int page, int pageSize) {
        try {
            PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, pageSize);
            Page<StageResultDocument> stageResultsPage = stageRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
            return toResultEntityList(stageResultsPage.getContent());
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, can you give us some other details (i.e. snippet of code)? Thank you

Comment: I found a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45093859/10077), but it doesn't look like there's much help there.

Comment: doesn't help that there is a typo in the message - it should say "greater" instead of "less"

Comment: Yes, there's a typo in the message :(

Comment: Added some code

Comment: You seem to be using the driver from 2019 or earlier, update it first.

Comment: Which version of the MongoDB API is your Cosmos DB using? 3.2, 3.6...?

Comment: Where can I see this information? It's a cosmos DB on Azure Cloud...

Answer (score 0):

We literally had the same error in our company. The issue seems to be related to Cosmos DB being not fully compatible with Mongo. This seems to be especially true if you want to use Cosmos DB as a file storage.

We run into this problem a couple of times and did not find any solution for this issue. Luckily we run early into this issue.

In the end we had to swallow the pill and moved our file storage to minio.